# SQL consulta de agrupaciones con datos iguales

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, while

el problema es el siguiente, tengo una tabla temporal en un SP con ciertos datos aqui un ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que busco es ir agregando en otra tabla temporal las AgrupacionesId que tengan el mismo ProductoId para utilizar esos datos en otro proceso, por ejemplo que tome las 2 primeras filas ya que ambas tiene el ProductoId igual, luego al terminar de usar esa tabla que la borre y cree otra con los siguientes ProductoId y asi sucesivamente

lo que se me ocurre es con un while pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo para que quede como quiero o si hay alguna otra opcion para hacer esto

espero haberme dado a entender y que alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: En primer lugar, crear y destruir tablas es una mala idea. La razon de una base de datos es la persistencia de la informacion. Pienso entonces, a que te refieres con "tabla temporal"? Creo que el concepto que necesitas implementar es el de una vista. Y donde quieres tener el codigo para agregar estas tablas temporales? En un disparador?

Comment: no estoy creando y destruyendo tablas de la base de datos, son tablas temporales dentro de un procedimiento almacenado el cual enviara conjuntos de datos por email, por eso estoy guardando esos conjuntos de datos en tablas temporales, para después de que se envié el primer conjunto seguir con el siguiente conjunto

Comment: Ahora se entiende el problema... haces una tabla temporal dentro de tu SP y luego la iteras. Ahora cual es el problema que tuviste ahi en particular

Answer (score 0):

Agrego consulta con comentarios:

```
create table #TablaInicial(
    ID int, 
    ProductoId int,
    AgrupacionId int, 
    Personas int
)
insert into #TablaInicial values(1, 23, 75, 1) 
insert into #TablaInicial values(1, 23, 76, 1) 
insert into #TablaInicial values(1, 25, 77, 1) 



-- seleccionar los diferentes ProductoId y guardarlos en una tabla
select distinct ProductoId 
into #ProductoIdTabla
from #TablaInicial

-- crear un cursor para recorrer los ProductoId
declare  ProductoIdCursor cursor  FAST_FORWARD FOR
select ProductoId from #ProductoIdTabla

-- variable para guardar el ProductoId actual
declare @ProductoId INT

open ProductoIdCursor
FETCH NEXT from ProductoIdCursor into @ProductoId


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- seleccionar los registros que tenga en el mismo @ProductoId
-- y guardarlos en la tabla temporal
select * 
into #TablaTemporal
from #TablaInicial 
where ProductoId = @ProductoId


-- aquí se usan los datos de la tabla temporal
select * from #TablaTemporal

-- vaciar la tabla temporal
drop table #TablaTemporal

FETCH NEXT from ProductoIdCursor into @ProductoId
END

close ProductoIdCursor
DEALLOCATE ProductoIdCursor


drop table #ProductoIdTabla
drop table #TablaInicial
```